# How to check a variable holds Instance or Type in c#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a class `Test`

```
public class Test { }
```

Now I have a variable `object1` which holds an instance of `Test`.

```
object object2 = new Test();

// some code

object2 = typeof(Test);
```

`object2` will accepts both type and instance of `Test` class in different scenario. How can I check what value it holds. i.e. Instance of `Test` or Type of `Test`

Comment: This sounds like a horrible design flaw, what are you trying to do by doing this?

Comment: Actually i was writing a framework which will automatically resolve a type if the instance is not there. above snippet just a mock to explain the scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (object2 is Test) { ... }
if (object2 is Type) { ... }
```

But don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Without having tested it you could check

```
if (object2 is Test) // .. we have an instance of Test
else if (object2 == typeof(Test)) // we have the second case
```

Btw.: this is bad design I suppose as a variable should be introduced for exact one purpose.

Comment: `is typeof`? Seriously?

Answer (score 1):

`if (object2 is Type) {...}` // when object2 is of type `Type`

`if (object2 is Test) {...}` // when object2 is of type `Test`.. hence holds an instance

Answer (score 1):

```
var object2Type = object2 as Type;
if (object2Type != null)
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    var object2Test = (Test)object2;
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also my library ([link](http://genericinvoker.codeplex.com/)):

```
object2.DetermineType()
       .When((Test target) => { /* action to do */ })
       .When((Type target) => { /* action to do */ })
       .Resolve();
```

or

```
object2.DetermineType()
       .When<Test>(target => { /* action to do */ })
       .When<Type>(target => { /* action to do */ })
       .Resolve();
```

But if you have to determine type this way, probably your design is not good.

Comment: Your library will be obsoleted by the next version of C#... New syntax `if (foo is Bar bar)` is proposed.

Comment: Maybe, but some people (like me) would prefer Fluent syntax anyway :)

Comment: Where're your libraries for fluent `If` and fluent `While`? The world totally needs them.

Comment: Fluent API is an **alternative**, not **replacement** for some problems. If you don't like them, just don;t use it.